# Server Side XML Document Manipulation in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, ms-word

I have a template for a loan document that I have saved in the directory of my asp.net MVC website. When the user clicks a clients name, I would like the website to edit the xml document using the clients information, then download the file as a word document. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: I suggest you do some research on LINQ to XML for the XML manipulation, and you'll want to use third-party tools to produce the Word document, unless DOCX format is ok for you. Do not use Office Interop.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Docentric Toolkit, which is a OpenXML based tool so no Word installation is necessary on the server. The tool comes with a MS Word Add-in, with which you can prepare templates with placeholders for data.

In your MVC application you then have to:

1. Prepare data model classes (e.g. with Entity Framework).
2. Create method which will read the data and fill the data model collection(s) as needed.
3. Call the method to generate Word document from the chosen template which is filled with data from data collection from step 2.

You can take a look at this CodeProject [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/759408/Creating-Word-documents-in-Net-using-Docentric-Too), to see detailed steps and download a demo project.

I hope this helps.